# IPython launching error with Enthought Python Distribution

Tags: macos, enthought

I have an Academic license with Enthought Python Distribution, and I'm getting a strange error when I try to run ipython. Here is some of the behavior I'm seeing:

```
$ ipython
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/Current/bin/ipython", line 8, in <module>
    from IPython import start_ipython
ImportError: cannot import name start_ipython

$ python
Enthought Python Distribution -- www.enthought.com
Version: 7.3-2 (64-bit)

Python 2.7.2 |EPD 7.3-2 (64-bit)| (default, Sep  7 2011, 16:31:15)
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5493)] on darwin
Type "credits", "demo" or "enthought" for more information.
>>> import IPython
>>> IPython.start_ipython()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'start_ipython'
>>>
```

When I run the enpkg enstaller, it updated ipython and it looked like everything worked OK.

```
$ sudo enpkg ipython
prefix: /Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.2
No update necessary, 'ipython' is up-to-date.
ipython-1.1.0-6.egg was installed on: Sun Jan 19 23:57:27 2014

$ which ipython
/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/Current/bin/ipython

$ which python
/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/Current/bin/python
```

Any help or suggestions what I can do to get ipython to work again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after looking around, I found a problem where someone said another install of ipython might be causing problems. enpkg is trying to install ipython 1.1.0 but I still had 0.13.1 around. So I removed it via:

```
$ sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipython-0.13.1-py2.7.egg
```

Then it loaded with errors about kernmagic so:

```
$ sudo enpkg kernmagic
```

It somehow re-installed ipython 1.0

```
$ ipython
Python 2.7.2 |EPD 7.3-2 (64-bit)| (default, Sep  7 2011, 16:31:15)
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 1.0.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
```

So simply re-trying the enpkg command installs the latest version.

```
$ sudo enpkg ipython
prefix: /Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.2
ipython-1.0.0-2.egg                                                [removing]
 12.84 MB [.................................................................]
Jinja2-2.6-2.egg                                                   [removing]
  1.58 MB [.................................................................]
tornado-2.2-1.egg                                                  [removing]
  1.42 MB [.................................................................]
tornado-3.1.1-1.egg                                              [installing]
  2.16 MB [.................................................................]
Jinja2-2.7.1-1.egg                                               [installing]
  1.62 MB [.................................................................]
ipython-1.1.0-6.egg                                              [installing]
 12.92 MB [.................................................................]

$ ipython
Python 2.7.2 |EPD 7.3-2 (64-bit)| (default, Sep  7 2011, 16:31:15)
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 1.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
```

And now it runs without errors. So, hopefully that helps anyone else coming across these kinds of problems.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue here on my Academic license with Enthought Python Distribution. I followed the steps outlined in answer and can confirm everything is working properly now. There's no mention of this solution on the Enthought Knowledge Base. Thanks!

One addition to the answer: in order to find the directory you need to remove from your system . . .

```
$ python
import IPython
print IPython
```